# Using usercontrol in Wfp on Button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am working with user controls.

I have a basic form that has 2 buttons btn_UC1, btn_UC2, and a panel
I have 2 user controls uc1, uc2 that have different tools to show various data
what I want to do:

On click of btn_UC1 I want to show uc1 in the panel
on click of btn_UC2 I want to show uc2 in the panel

But I don't want to close, clear, remove uc1 on click of btn_UC2, it should be in the background.

And same functionality on click of btn_UC1

Also when I close uc2, it should show uc1

I have tried using the clear functionality where the panel.cchildren.clear is called before showing any of the usercontrol.

```
C# WPF
        UC1 Control1 = new UC1();
        UC2 Control2 = new UC2();



 private void btn_UC1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //pnl_UC.Children.Remove(Control2);
                pnl_UC.Children.Clear();
                pnl_UC.Children.Add(Control1);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {


            }

        }

 private void btn_UC2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                pnl_UC.Children.Remove(Control1);
                // pnl_UC.Children.Clear();
                pnl_UC.Children.Add(Control2);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {


            }

        }
```

```xml
    <Window x:Class="UserControlTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlTest"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="449.024" Width="870.182"
             >
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btn_UC1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" Height="34" Click="btn_UC1_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_UC2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159" Height="34" Click="btn_UC2_Click"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="pnl_UC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" Margin="281,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="573">

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, I can't seem to find a question in your question, mind [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55374610/edit)ing your question to include it? Also while you're at it, may I ask you to format your code a little? Right now it's horrendous to look at and makes it (for me at least) unnecessarily hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

You are removing Control1 from panel on click of btn_UC2. remove this from you code like below

```
private void btn_UC2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {

               pnl_UC.Children.Add(Control2);
           }
           catch (Exception err)
           {


           }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an ItemsControl with a binding on an ObservableCollection, and from your codebehind you can Add / Remove things from this ObservableCollection. It's more mvvm.